# vcpkg cannot open source file errors with mlpack

Tags: c++, vcpkg, mlpack

im currently trying to install vcpkg and mlpack, i have bootstraped vcpkg and ive integrate the install and also installed mlpack but when i go on to visual studio and try and do #include  i get the error that it cannot open source file "mlpack.hpp". I have my visual studio installed on my C drive but vcpkg installed on my E drive, could that be the issue? Or is there something else i should've done within visual studio or the windows powershell in order to use the header files. Any help is appreciated and let me know if you need anymore information. Thanks

also i have added the include folder path to the include directories sections of VC++ directorys the lib folder path to the libary directors section and it still has the same error
the error goes away when i specify the specific path beyond the include folder where mlpack.hpp is but then i have loads of other errors about not being able to open loads of other source files, so im guessing if i added every folder with .hpp files in then it would work but surely there is an easier way than this? could it maybe be because i downloaded the zip of github instead of doing the git clone command?

any help much appreciated, thanks

Spoken about above. I have also tried debugging the issue with chatgpt and still no luck

Comment: ***I have my visual studio installed on my C drive but vcpkg installed on my E drive, could that be the issue?*** No. I have vcpkg on my X drive with Visual Studio on my C drive.

Comment: Maybe you need to add both `include` and `include/mlpack` (or similar) folders.